# Glitch or mate?

Tags: software

Whilst playing a casual game against computer on an iPhone app I was faced with this situation.

[image]

With white to move, the computer tells me I have a saving move but I clearly do not.

Am I right in thinking this is a glitch or is there an obscure play that I could have used to save my King?

Comment: For future reference, it's not at all obvious whether "white" means the brown pieces or the grey ones. In this case, we can figure it out because one side is in check (in fact, mate) but there's no other way to tell. (For example, the grey isn't darker than the brown, the board could have been reversed, etc.)

Comment: TBH i think the comp is taunting you XD jk but thats weird tho lol

Comment: I've this happen to me as well. If I were you I'd report it as a bug.

Comment: Did you try Ne4? Maybe it thinks you can save by checking the black King? Still mate though, just curious.

Comment: Yes I tried every move available to me but it kept making the 'check' sound to indicate I must move out of check.

The glitch surprised me because I've played this app over several years and never had a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the last move was ...Re1 it sure looks like mate to me.

Comment: No need to assume anything about the last move; the position is now what it is now.